# R - importing a file using read.xlsx2 appends a 0 the end of certain cells

Tags: r

When I read in an .xlsx file with a cell format of 0.00#, the resulting value that is imported is 0.00#0 (eg, if I read in an excel file with one cell with a value of "0.006", the corresponding data frame is a one cell value of "0.0060", formatted as a factor). I need to keep this as a factor.

Everything else I've tried does not have this problem. 0.111 for eg does not get read in as 0.1110, 0.1 is not read in as 0.10, etc.

It does not appear to be a "hidden" 0 in Excel, or anything to do with formatting in Excel, but I could be wrong.

Comment: `read.xlsx2` is built for speed compared to `read.xlsx`. You can try specifying the class for the columns. If that doesn't work, reading it in as is may not be difficult to eliminate the terminal `0`.

Comment: using 'read.xlsx' while specifying classes for the columns works to solve that issue. However, I will be using it to read some very large files and speed is important

Comment: have you tried `openxlsx`? It's fast for me. And again, if speed is important, read in the files with that extra zero at the end and just use a regex to take it away.

Comment: hmm any idea how to take it away using your second option? They all seem to be in that 0.00#0 format, but it is mixed in numerous columns and rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
num <- c("0.0040", "0.0130", "1.200", "0.001")
num2 <- c("0.0060", "0.1020", "0.0080", "0.0090")
df <- data.frame(x = as.factor(num), y = as.factor(num2))
df
       x      y
1 0.0040 0.0060
2 0.0130 0.1020
3  1.200 0.0080
4  0.001 0.0090

nozeroes <- function(df) {
  erased <- Map(function(x) gsub('0+$', '', x), df)
  as.data.frame(erased)
}
nozeroes(df)
      x     y
1 0.004 0.006
2 0.013 0.102
3   1.2 0.008
4 0.001 0.009
```

## Update

Since you now asked for a different number format:

```
#new data
num <- c("0.0040", "0.0130", "1.200", "0.001", "10")
num2 <- c("0.0060", "0.1020", "0.0080", "0.0090", "10")
df2 <- data.frame(x = as.factor(num), y = as.factor(num2))

nozeroes2 <- function(df) {
  erased <- Map(function(x) gsub('(^0.*)0+$', '\\1', x), df)
  as.data.frame(erased)
}
nozeroes2(df2)
      x     y
1 0.004 0.006
2 0.013 0.102
3 1.200 0.008
4 0.001 0.009
5    10    10
```

In the future, be advised that you will get the help that you ask for and not wider case solutions that are not mentioned.

Comment: hmm that's good, thanks! Unfortunately it looks like it truncates all 0's, thus a 10 becomes a 1...

Comment: I can only help you as much as the information you give. If you say that your data is in the form 0.00#0 then I will help you with that. It's an easy fix though.

Comment: Right sorry! My data is in all different kinds of forms, but the only ones who end up with the appended 0 is the ones in the 0.00# format which becomes 0.00#0.